# Solving a simple system.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

I'm actually working with the Jordan Canonical form I should solve this simple equation:

$Av_2 = v_1 + 2v_2$

simplify:

$(A - 2I)v_2 = v_1$

now I plug in my known matrix and vector and after subtracting the identity the system looks like that:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&4&3\\-1&-2&-1\\1&2&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

how do I solve this?
Can I simplify it to row echelon form?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is just a regular linear system that can be converted to row echelon form.

Notice that the second and third rows are negative of each other.

You can perform the row operations $R_3+ R_2$ and $R_2 + R_1$ to convert it to row echelon form.

Remark: There are infinitely many solutions to the system.

Comment: So then the solution would be $x_1 -x_3 = 1 $ and $x_2 + x_3 =-1$ ? but how does the vector look like?

Comment: If $x_3= t$, can you solve for $x_1$ and $x_2$ in terms of $t$?

Comment: $x_1 = 1 + t$ and $x_2 = -1 - t$ ?

Comment: awesome. $(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (1, -1, 0) + t (1, -1, 1)$

Comment: How can I add that to a basis of eigenvectors?

Comment: You don't. I think what you want to find is generalized eigenvector https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector Try to follow example $2$ in the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65016/discussion-between-leroy-and-siong-thye-goh).

Comment: Correction. $(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (1,0,0) + t(1,-1,1)$.